# How to calculate difference on grouped df?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
name      date      value
 a      1/1/2011      3
 b      1/1/2011      5
 c      1/1/2011      7
 a      1/2/2011      6
 b      1/2/2011      10
 c      1/2/2011      14
```

I have a df here where the value is cumulative stats. So the Actual value of `name: a` `date: 1/2/2011` is 3 not 6. To get the actual value of a particular day, I need to take that day's value minus the previous day's value. I want to calculate the actual value of each name for each date. Something along the lines of `df.groupby(['name', 'date'])['value'].diff()` but this code is returning error.

In the end what I need is

```
name      date   actual value
 a      1/1/2011      3
 b      1/1/2011      5
 c      1/1/2011      7
 a      1/2/2011      3
 b      1/2/2011      5
 c      1/2/2011      7
```

Comment: Sorry, typo. I fixed it now

Comment: `df['value'] = df.groupby('name').diff(1).fillna(df['value'])` gets us closer but won't fill the `NaN`. After being a bit shocked by that, I've come across similar approaches suggesting the same thing. Has something changed?

Comment: Yea, I changed the `actual value` column, there was a typo. I'm going to run your code really fast and see what happens.

Comment: It will pull out the original values, but I am confused why it's not catching the values and yet others have listed the same approach on other questions and it's apparently working

Comment: I would try `df.groupby("name")` instead of `["name", "date"]`. There's also a `shift` function that might help you do the subtraction.

Comment: With the help of @ALollz we found that `df.groupby('name').diff(1).fillna(df[['value']])` works, but neither of us are sure why you have to reference the complete dataframe so we're not comfortable posting as an answer until we figure it out. Happy for any guidance on that.

Comment: @roganjosh When you say "reference the complete dataframe", where are you referring to?

Comment: Quick question, my actual data has 67546 rows. I have been running `df['actual value'] = df.groupby('name').diff(1).fillna(df['value'])` for the past 30 minutes and its still not complete. Does this sound normal to you guys?

Comment: If you look at the documentation of `fillna`, (my guess is) since `value` can be a series, which you have provided as `df[['value']`, the fillna method will fill the na's by index. Since `diff` makes the indices 0,1,2 `na`, the fillna method fills in the values corresponding to those indices

Comment: Yes, I think (hope) they are writing an answer up. There is a `NotImplementedError` that means that technically you have to use the Series.

Comment: @IDontKnowAnything depends on how many "abcde..." you have?  Also they've only posted that in the comments since 7 minutes ago?

Comment: @AsheKetchum I have around 3000 "abcde". I started running it since roganjosh's second comment.

Comment: @IDontKnowAnything firstly kill that code. You want `df.groupby('name').diff(1).fillna(df[['value']])` (note the double brackets). Second, no, it shouldn't take anything close to that time. I would say that the speed issue is elsewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['value'] = df['value'].fillna(method='ffill')
df = df.sort_values(by=['name', 'date'])
df['actual'] = df.groupby(['name'])['value'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved the issue, but I can't change to solved yet.

Comment: glad to hear :-) please select my answer as best if possible

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in a single line and in a vectorized way.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard() # Reading from your question

df['value'] = df.groupby('name')['value'].diff(1).fillna(df['value'])
```

As was discussed in the comments, it is necessary to reference the original `'values` Series when applying `fillna` to correctly replace the `NaN` values from `diff` (this occurs for the first instance of each label in `'name'`).

Comment: you can probably change this to df.groupby('name')['value'].diff(1) to be a little cleaner.

Comment: @AndyHayden the issue is that you get `NaN` for the first 3, since there is no `diff` to be had. Unless I've misunderstood your suggestion, the `fillna` is necessary to catch those values.

Comment: I just meant switch .diff(1)['value'] to ['value'].diff(1), yup the fillna is needed. my bad on not just including the last part!

Comment: @AndyHayden actually, it's probably faster too I would think since it limits to the Series but on my phone atm so can't check. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @roganjosh I want to thank you sincerely for working on this for such a long time.

Comment: @IDontKnowAnything you're very welcome. But don't forget that good questions are not just for you; I now learned something too :)